# Transational won't rollback @Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am attempting to add a rollback mechanism to my spring project, having followed a few tutorials I still can't resolve the issue why the rollback won't happen in the following code:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = TransactionException.class)
    public boolean changeSquad(ArrayList<Integer> playerIdList, String email) {
        boolean squadChanged = false;

        // Obtain the current list of players from the persistent storage
        TypedQuery<Player> playersQuery = emgr.createNamedQuery("Player.getUsersPlayers", Player.class);
        playersQuery.setParameter("email", email);



        List<Player> currentPlayerList = playersQuery.getResultList();

        // Make a copy of the list obtained as method parameter
        ArrayList<Integer> playerIdListCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(playerIdList);

        // Make a copy of the list obtained from persistent storage
        ArrayList<Player> currentPlayerListCopy = new ArrayList<Player>(currentPlayerList);
        System.out.println("current player list copy = " + currentPlayerListCopy);



        // Iterate through each player from the currentPlayerList
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayerListCopy.size(); i++) {
            // On each iteration check if the playerIdList contains currently iterated 
            // Player's id, if so then eliminate it from both lists
            int playerId = currentPlayerListCopy.get(i).getPlayer_id();

            if (playerIdListCopy.contains(playerId)) {
                currentPlayerListCopy.remove(i);
                playerIdListCopy.remove(playerIdListCopy.indexOf(playerId));
                i--;
            }

        }
        // IF copy of current player list AND playerId list is empty, proceed
        if (currentPlayerListCopy.isEmpty() && playerIdListCopy.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("currentPlayerListCopy && playerIdListCopy = empty");

            // Make the squad changes

            for (int j = 0; j < currentPlayerList.size(); j++) {
                Player tempPlayer = currentPlayerList.get(j);
                int tempPlayerId = tempPlayer.getPlayer_id();

                // LOOP for all players from the client side list
                for (int n = 0; n < playerIdList.size(); n++) {
                    if (playerIdList.get(n) == tempPlayerId) {
                        ......
                    } 
                } // END loop for all players from the client side list 

                emgr.persist(tempPlayer);
                if (j == 13) {
                    System.out.println("j13, throwing exception");
                    try {
                        throw new TransactionException("sh.t happens");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("thrown and catched");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } // END loop for the player from the server side list
        } else {
            System.out.println("Seems like somebody messed up with the values.");
        }
        return squadChanged;
    }
```

Upon the TransactionException being thrown I would except the rollback mechanism to work, however it doesn't and the entity is persisted..

The following is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">

    <!-- CREATES DATA SOURCE -->
    <!-- <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url"
            value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + 'localhost' + ':' + '5432' + '/handball' }" />
        <property name="username" value="'#{ 'postgres' }" />
        <property name="password" value="#{ '........' }" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="emf">
        <!-- Entities location -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="af.handball.entity"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

         <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>  

    </bean>
</beans>
```

I would appreciate any information given on where i could had gone wrong, Thanks!

Comment: Where is the configuration of TransactionManager? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't catch exceptions in your transactional method. The transactional functionality is implemented by a proxy that wraps the service object. The exceptions have to reach the proxy in order for the proxy to know it needs to rollback. If you catch the exception within the service method then the proxy doesn't know the transaction was supposed to fail.

Delete the try-catch block around your exception and let the exception be thrown, and you should see the transaction get rolled back.